# JSON, Stomp and ActiveMQ

Tags: java, php, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

Ok, so here's the deal.
I was reading [this tutorial](http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html) and the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) from the ActiveMQ website.

On the documentation we have, under *Message Transformations*, this sentence:

> The transformation message header on SEND and SUBSCRIBE messages could
>   be used to instruct ActiveMQ to transform messages from text to the
>   format of your desire. Currently, ActiveMQ comes with a transformer
>   that can transform XML/JSON text to Java objects

and

> ActiveMQ uses XStream for its transformation needs. Since it's the
>   optional dependency you have to add it to broker's classpath by
>   putting the appropriate JAR into the lib/ folder. Additionally, if you
>   plan to use JSON transformations you have to add Jettison JSON parser
>   to the classpath.

So I did this, I've annotated my pojo with *XStreamAlias*:

```
@XStreamAlias("ProvaPojo")
public class ProvaPojo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1687248536279612587L;

    @XStreamAlias("fieldOne")
    private int fieldOne;

    @XStreamAlias("fieldTwo")
    private String fieldTwo;

    public int getFieldOne() {
    return fieldOne;
    }

    public void setFieldOne(int fieldOne) {
    this.fieldOne = fieldOne;
    }

    public String getFieldTwo() {
    return fieldTwo;
    }

    public void setFieldTwo(String fieldTwo) {
    this.fieldTwo = fieldTwo;
    }

}
```

And this is my PHP code (original example is [here](http://stomp.fusesource.org/documentation/php/book.html#Message_Transformation)):

```
$body = array(
        'ProvaPojo' => array(
            array('fieldOne' =>  14),
            array('fieldTwo' => 'Stringa')
        )
);

$header = array();
$header['transformation'] = 'jms-map-json';
$mapMessage = new StompMessageMap($body, $header);
$con->send($queue, $mapMessage);
```

And this is my listener

```
@Override
protected void _onMessage(Message message) {
if (!(message instanceof ObjectMessage))
    throw new IllegalStateException();
ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
try {
    if (!(objectMessage.getObject() instanceof BlacklisterRecipientBean))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "The message content is not an instance of "
                    + BlacklisterRecipientBean.class.getSimpleName());
    BlacklisterRecipientBean recipient = (BlacklisterRecipientBean) objectMessage
        .getObject();
    log.info("_onMessage(Message)");
    IncomingBlacklistAddJMSTrigger trigger = new IncomingBlacklistAddJMSTrigger();
    trigger.setArgs(recipient);
    notifyObservers(trigger);
} catch (JMSException e) {
    log.error("_onMessage(Message) - exception ignored", e);
}

}
```

But I'm always getting an ActiveMQTextMessage. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apperently it was a problem of my activeMQ version. Once switched to `5.8.0` everything worked like a charm.